# sql query - selection of a correct row from a groups specified by id

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    id  risk    origin  strength    strength_sol
    13456   1   1   3   3
    13456   134 0   5   NULL
    13456   128 0   7   NULL
    13456   121 0   5   NULL
    13456   122 0   4   NULL
    13456   190 0   2   NULL
    22367   1   1   5   5
    22367   128 0   4   NULL
    22367   1   0   2   NULL
    22367   36  0   6   NULL
    12789   1   1   5   5
    12789   1   0   4   NULL
    12789   118 1   2   NULL
    12789   118 1   5   NULL
    12789   1   0   7   NULL
    16908   1   0   5   5
    16908   36  0   4   NULL
    16908   28  1   3   NULL
    16908   128 1   5   NULL
    16908   1   0   7   NULL
    12439   1   0   4   4
    12439   134 0   2   NULL
    12439   16  0   5   NULL
    15678   36  0   4   NULL
    15678   28  0   2   NULL
    15678   134 0   5   NULL
```

**Problem and data description:**
I have a big dataset. Above you can see just a small sample in order to describe my problem.

I need to choose exactly one row for each id.

In the dataset above there are all the possible cases that can happen.

The last two columns are not a part of the data set. They are the result that I need to get.
Origin is a 0/1 variable.

I need to choose this:
for one id:

1. situation: when risk = 1 and origin = 1 - Im ok, I will take this
   row, there can be the only row like this for one id in the dataset
2. situation: when for one id there is no case that risk=1 and origin =1, I have to choose the row where risk=1 and origin = 0,  if there are more such a rows, it doesn't matter which one I choose(But I have
   to choose only ONE of them, not all of them).
3. when there in no risk = 1 in any row for one id (doesnt matter what is the value of the origin), I just simply put `NULL` as
   `strength_sol`

My solution is like this (but it is not correct):

```
case when risk=1 and origin =1 then strength  
when risk=1 and origin = 0 then strength  
else NULL end as strength
```

This solution is not correct, because in the situation number one can happen that there is also a row with risk=1 and origin=0, but I'm not interested in that row (I want NULL for that row).

Comment: Can you provide the SQL snippet?

Comment: which dbms is being used?

Comment: microsof sql management studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` function to number the rows so that the first row would be the one with highest priority (in this case risk=1 and origin=1) and the second with the next highest priority (risk=1 and origin=0). All the other rows are numbered arbitrarily and then you can choose the first row from each group.

```
select id,risk,origin,strength,
case when rnum=1 then strength end strength_sol
from (select t.*,
      row_number() over(partition by id 
                        order by case when risk=1 and origin =1 then 1 
                                      when risk=1 and origin =0 then 2 
                                 else 3 end) rnum
      from t
      ) x
```

Comment: it seems fine, but I really need to create a new column like strength_sol (as the one in the dataset above), because i will use that column later in other view... in my dataset I have much more columns and I need to use all the information. I will need information also for the rows with strength_sol=NULL. thanks.

Comment: @kvietok .. i edited the answer so you get all the rows

Comment: it is working :). It does not work just for the situation number 3. So I made a small change in the code. I m putting the code in the answer. Thank you very much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    this is the final code :)

SELECT
    id
   ,risk
   ,origin
   ,strength
   ,CASE
        WHEN (X.rnum = 1 AND risk = 1) THEN strength
        ELSE NULL
    END AS strength_sol
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t.*
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY id
                ORDER BY CASE
                    WHEN risk = 1 AND
                        origin = 1 THEN 1
                    WHEN risk = 1 AND
                        origin = 0 THEN 2
                    ELSE 3
                END
            ) rnum
        FROM
            t
    ) AS [X]
```